# How to Marshal a C struct with a byte * field for C# with DLLImport

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling

I am trying to figure how to correctly Marshal a C structure containing a byte * field so I can send commands to a third-party API from a C# application. However I keep receiving errors complaining about parameters. This is what I have, from C code:

```
struct MY_STRUCT
{
    int32 Object;            // Object index, dependent of the context
    int32 Cmd;               // Command code
    byte *Params;            // pointer to parameters
};

int32 stdcall SendCommand( int32 DeviceId, MY_STRUCT *Cmd );
```

This is how I'm currently referencing to it on my C# code:

```
public struct MY_STRUCT
{
    public Int32 Object;            // Object index, dependent of the context
    public Int32 Cmd;               // Command code
    public IntPtr Params;           // pointer to parameters
};

[DllImport("C:\\Client.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Int32 SendCommand( Int32 DeviceId, ref MY_STRUCT Cmd );

Int32 CSharpSendCommand( int placa, int chan, int code, String parametros )
    {
        MY_STRUCT cmd = new MY_STRUCT();
        cmd.Cmd = code;
        cmd.Object = chan;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[parametros.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(parametros.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
        try { 
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, p, parametros.Length);
            cmd.Params = p;
            Int32 ret = Translated.SendCommand( placa, ref cmd );
            if (ret != (int)LibraryStatus.Success)
                Console.Out.Write("Erro: Comando 0x{0} retornou: {1}\n", code, ret);

            return ret;
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
        }
    }
```

Any guesses? It works really fine when sending primitive types like Byte, Int32, so on an so forth...

Comment: This MSDN code may give you an idea how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0szztey7.aspx

Comment: The odds that the C code will understand the string the way you are doing now are about zilch.  Use Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi().  This is otherwise just wild guessing without a spec.

Comment: Could you share the error message or error code?

Comment: @Sjips unfortunately error code is API specific and doesn't bring any light to the issue. It translates to "invalid parameters"...

Comment: @HansPassant I guess I would put some money on that... Will try this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @HansPassant That's it! It worked fine. I would give you guys +10 if possible. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that you're confusing bytes and characters. In particular, you have this:

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[parametros.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(parametros.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
```

This is essentially correct in that you're taking into account that a `char` is two bytes in length. But then you have:

```
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, p, parametros.Length);
```

This is a problem because you're only copying `parametros.Length` bytes, which is exactly half the length of the `bytes` array.

I think you want to change that to `bytes.Length`.

The other problem I see is that you're not supplying anything that says how long that sequence of bytes is (i.e. no `cbParams` value, or similar), and no null terminator if it's supposed to be treated like a string.

And, as Hans Passant points out, it's unlikely that the C code would understand a bunch of 2-byte "characters", anyway. His suggestion to use `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi` is probably right on the money.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi did the trick!